# Which Spark package is suitable with caret?

Tags: r, apache-spark

I used to building predictive model with caret package and parallel computing (in memory) with DoSnow package.
I would like to switch on the CLOUD in order to reduce computation time.

Any Spark-like package will be compatible with caret ?

Thank you very much !
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark has a ML library that works with dataframes : ml

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html

there is also ml pipeline

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-pipeline.html

Comment: Hello Brian ! Thank you for the answer, however your comment isn't appropriate. I know it exists Spark-like packages such as sparklyr, SparkR.
I just would like to know it exists a Spark-like packages that use caret !
Best regards

Comment: then no, caret is very good but will not interface with spark.